# Java Cplex Product of two Decision Variables

Tags: java, cplex

Is there a way to get the product of two different decision variables in cplex java and add it to an objective function?

Ex.

decision variable -> x[i]

decision variable -> y[j]

-> x[i]*y[j]

Such a multiplikation should be possible, since it is still linear right?

Comment: No, its not linear. You are going quadratic.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I thought that in order to get a quadratic function, the same decision variable had to be multiplied -> x*x = x^2. Is there then still a way to write such a code in cplex?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the examples that are shipped with CPLEX? For example, the `QPex1.java` program shows you exactly how to do this.

Comment: Oh my. Thank you. The example is perfect. I was looking the whole time at examples that were linear. This is the reason why, I could not find an answer.

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, if you'd like to earn some reputation points, feel free to provide a more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to this question (it's perfectly legal and encouraged to answer and "accept" your own answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to

@TimChippingtonDerrick (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108433/timchippingtonderrick)

and

@rkersh (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1718477/rkersh)

I have found the answer to my problem.

At first such an objective function is not linear. This is the reason why for example

`IloLinearNumExpr expressionName = cplex.linearNumExpr();
expressionName.addTerm(x[i],y[j]);`

will not work, since such a multiplication is not being supported in a linear model. Only a variable with a coefficient can be added to such a linear expression.

For the second part, through the example provided by Cplex `QPex1.java`

I could write the product of two decision variables and add them to an objective function as in the following example:

```
IloNumExpr objective = cplex.numExpr();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        objective = cplex.sum(objective,cplex.prod(y[i], z[j][i]));
    }
}
cplex.addMinimize(objective);
```